# If $\vec u, \vec v, \vec w$ are linearly independent, will $\vec u + \vec v, \vec u + \vec w, \vec v + \vec w$ also be linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra

Since the three vectors are linearly independent we have: $c_1\vec u + c_2 \vec v, 
+c_3\vec w = 0$ if and only if $c_1=c_2=c_3=0$.

But how do I utilize this to prove the conclusion?

Comment: Look at $a_1(\vec{u} + \vec{v}) + a_2(\vec{u} + \vec{w}) + a_3(\vec{v} + \vec{w}) = 0$. Rearrange. Can you conclude $a_1 = a_2 = a_3 = 0$?

Comment: Call your new vectors $x,y,z$ and write $c_1x+c_2y+c_3z=0$. Then write in terms of $u,v,w$ and use your definition. Can any of the $c_i$ be nonzero?

Comment: @DanielFischer: After rearranging I get: $a_1 a_2\vec u + a_1 a_3 \vec v 
+ a_2 a_3 \vec w = 0$ From the premise it follows that $a_1 a_2 = 0, a_1 a_3 = 0, a_2 a_3 =0$. But for this to be true isn't it enough if just two of these three coeffiecients are zero? E.g., if $a_1 = 0,  a_2 = 0$ it is enough for the equations to hold. How can I then conclude anything about the nature of $a_3$?

dafinguzman: I believe your approach gets me to the same position right?

Comment: How do you get products of the coefficients? You should get sums. And whether it implies $a_1 = a_2 = a_3 = 0$ depends on the scalar field.

Comment: Oh, I see. Well of course it works out if I do it correctly. The equations can then only be true if all of the coefficients are 0. I haven't studied scalar fields - isn't this enough to conclude that $a_1 = a_2 = a_3 = 0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a_1(\vec{u}+\vec{v})+a_2(\vec{v}+\vec{w})+a_3(\vec{w}+\vec{u})=\vec{0}$. Using the linear independence of $\vec{u},\vec{v},\vec{w}$ you get $a_1+a_2=a_2+a_3=a_3+a_1=0$, which implies $2a_1=2a_2=2a_3=0$.

Now, if you are working with a vector space over a field of [characteristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_%28algebra%29) different from 2 (i.e. a field in which $1+1\neq0$, such as $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$), this implies $a_1=a_2=a_3=0$, so your vectors are linearly independent. Otherwise, they are not independent since $(\vec{u}+\vec{v})+(\vec{v}+\vec{w})+(\vec{w}+\vec{u})=\vec{0}$, having used the fact that $\vec{u}+\vec{u}=(1+1)\vec{u}=0\vec{u}=\vec{0}$.